# R9 380x low hash rate issues

Tags: hardware

I have the Tahonga R9 380x

I am on `Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS` using the Open CL version: `15.201-0ubuntu0.14.04.1` which i got after running the `apt-cache policy flgrx` command.

The drivers are not headless meaning I have to use a display to do some stuff etc. fan control

According to https://www.cryptocompare.com/mining/sapphire/radeon-r9-380x-ethereum-mining/ , I should be getting around 24 MH/s per card.

The way I see it, this could be due to the following reasons:

1. **Drivers.** The drivers are not optimal for mining. This is however countered by this [guys answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/3038/2219) that claims that `15.x` drivers are better than `16.x`  's
2. **Thermal throttling.** Le card is throttling itself. Maybe I need to fiddle with some settings to increase thermal headroom? This is however countered by the Saphire's giant ass heatsink and the fans don't even kick in till about 40% load.
3. **OS.** The OS is the problem. Maybe I need to go a full headless setup by installing Ubuntu Server. Because what I currently use has a desktop environment, even though no display is attached since I SSH into the rig. Maybe the desktop environment is stealing some GPU hashing power?

Inputs from anyone with the same config or related would be highly appreciated.

Comment: what hashrate you got compared with this supposed 24MH/s ?

Comment: 19 MH/s and occasionally it dips down to 15

Comment: I don't see anything obvious in your config. The only thing that comes to mind is that the 24 has been calculated a few months ago when the difficulty was lower, I'd check what others may have currently with a 380x

Comment: Okay. Let me go to the ethereum mining forums and ask someone for benchmarks on their 380x. Hopefully someone shall reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cryptocompare informations looks strange for this card, I don't saw reports of such a hashrate with a R9 380x.
I've got an Asus one, overclocked to the limit at a very cool temp (46°C) and I barely have 20 or 21MH/s. I also run Ubuntu 14.04 and all is up to date. Also Cryptocompare data are odd for power consumption as I don't really know what unit the use but for a 380x if unit is Watt it's more between 170 and 180, not 400.

http://gpuboss.com/graphics-card/Radeon-R9-380X

> Power
>
> AMD has been behind NVIDIA in power consumption efficiency for a while
>   now, and the R9 380X is no exception, but given the total heat output
>   is well manageable with around 170 W, the thermal solutions doesn't
>   have to be big and bulky.

Some other people were afraid of this 20MH/s, but it seems normal.
See https://fanbitcoin.com/index.php?topic=1279983.5;wap2

> My 380x is doing 20Mh.
>
> I think this value is very reasonable. 280x is faster than 380x at the
>   same frequency. It is better to buy a 7970 for hashing.

And we all agree that the R9 7970 is a good card but you won't find it at low prices nowadays.

https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/comment/16487/#Comment_16487

> Stats for R9 380X
>
> min/mean/max: 19835562/19957896/20010325 H/s inner mean: 13311089 H/s

You can also have a look at calculators that propose a list of cards. For https://cryptowizzard.github.io/eth-mining-calculator/ the R9 380x is preset at 20MH/s.